# JS array problems - slice array 'b' and 'a' is sliced too

Tags: javascript

I have 2 arrays: A and B, when I change one both change. Is there a way to edit one without changing the other one.

```
a = [[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]] 
b = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]]
a = b.slice(0)
a[0][0] = 10
console.log(a) /* [[10,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]] */ 
console.log(b) /* [[10,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]] */
```

The a is fine but I need b to stay [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]]

Comment: When you slice b and assign it to a, a now references b. You need to make sure they are not references of each other.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copying array by value in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copying-array-by-value-in-javascript)

Comment: You can use  `a = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(b));`  instead of `a = b.slice(0)` 
`slice()` , `contat()` works for shallow copying i.e. for single dimensional array.

Answer (score 4):

When you  do `splice`, you change the reference of `a` and `b`, however, the reference of arrays in array b still share references, hence, update your code to following. Use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
a = [[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]] 
b = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]]
a = b.map(x => [...x])
a[0][0] = 10
console.log(a) /* [[10,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]] */ 
console.log(b) /* [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]] */
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map` to `slice` each array.

```js
a = [[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]] 
b = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]]
a = b.map(o=>o.slice(0));
a[0][0] = 10
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

Doc: [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 2):

You take a shallow copy with [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), which means nested arrays are taken by their object reference.

You could use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with a check for arrays and map these recursively.

```js
const deep = a => Array.isArray(a) ? a.map(deep) : a;

var a = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
    b = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]];

a = b.map(deep);
a[0][0] = 10;

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

[slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), like [Object.freeze()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) have a shallow scope, so this works:

```
var a = [1,2,3,4];
var b = a.slice(0);

a[0] = 10;
console.log(b); // [1, 2, 3]
console.log(a); // [10, 2, 3, 4]
```

But this doesn't work:

```
var a = [[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]]; //multidimensional!
var b = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]];

a = b.slice(0);
a[0][0] = 10;
console.log(a); 
console.log(b);
```

Then, the key is go deep with `slice()`, `for` or something, Here an example using for:

```
var a = []; 

for (var i = 0, len = b.length; i < len; i++) {
    a[i] = b[i].slice();
}
```

Keep in mind that **const** won't work:

```
var a = [[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]]; 
const b = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]];// doesn't work

var a = b.slice(0);

a[0][0] = 10; // a changes b
console.log(a); 
console.log(b);
```